# Вывод совокупной стоимости

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, дана задача: Написать программу, в которой пользователь с клавиатуры заполняет словарь с ключами: материал, стоимость единицы, количество, фио заказчика. Вывести после заполнения общее количество всех различных материалов (заполнить так, чтобы строки с одинаковыми материалами повторялись некоторые) и их совокупную стоимость.

```
choice = 1
while choice != 'нет':
    choice = 0
    name = input('Введите имя ключа: ')
    material = input('Введите материал: ')
    stoim = input('Введите стоимость единицы: ')
    kolvo = input('Кол-во: ')
    fio = input('ФИО заказчика: ')
    total = material, stoim, kolvo, fio
    d = {}
    d = {name: total}
    choice = input('Хотите продолжить заполнение? да/нет')
    if choice == 'да':
        newname = input('Введите имя ключа: ')
        material = input('Введите материал: ')
        stoim = input('Введите стоимость единицы: ')
        kolvo = input('Кол-во: ')
        fio = input('ФИО заказчика: ')
        total = material, stoim, kolvo, fio
        choice = input('Хотите продолжить заполнение? да/нет')
        d = {newname:total}
    print(d)
```

Написал такой код, но проблема в следующем: Не могу понять как можно вывести совокупную стоимость?

Comment: Для начала вам нужно решить эту часть - "_Вывести после заполнения общее количество всех различных материалов"_. А потом можно будет перейти к общей стоимости

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
while choice != 'нет':
    choice = 0
    name = input('Введите имя ключа: ')
    material = input('Введите материал: ')
    stoim = input('Введите стоимость единицы: ')
    kolvo = input('Кол-во: ')
    fio = input('ФИО заказчика: ')
    total = material, stoim, kolvo, fio
    d[name] = total
    choice = input('Хотите продолжить заполнение? да/нет')
    if choice == 'да':
        newname = input('Введите имя ключа: ')
        material = input('Введите материал: ')
        stoim = input('Введите стоимость единицы: ')
        kolvo = input('Кол-во: ')
        fio = input('ФИО заказчика: ')
        total = material, stoim, kolvo, fio
        choice = input('Хотите продолжить заполнение? да/нет')
        d = {newname:total}
print(d)

stoimost = {}
for k in d:
    i = d[k]
    if stoimost.get(k) == None:
        stoimost[k] = float(i[1]) * int(i[2])
    else:
        stoimost[k] += float(i[1]) * int(i[2])
print("----------price list------------")
for material in stoimost:
    print("{}:{}".format(material, stoimost[material]))
```

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы при совпадении двух материалов был выведен 1 подсчёт. Например :
кирпич, 40, 100, А 
плаcтик, 20, 20,A 
кирпич, 10, 10, Ф 
 
Вывод программы: 
корпич 4100 
пластик 400

Comment: @StrixCorp тогда почему вы словарь d обнуляете на каждой итерации? ```d = {}
    d = {name: total}```

Comment: @StrixCorp потому что автор думает, что решил половину задачи, хотя на самом деле не решил.

Comment: @StrixCorp я изменил код в ответе, так вам нужно?

Comment: @ЕлисейИонов Ввожу 3 материала по очереди: кирпич, пластмасса, а потом снова кирпич. Первый ключ пропадает и остаётся только последний. Нужно сделать так, чтоб можно было вводить кучу раз одинакового материала, а выводилось одной строкой общая сумма этого материала